# Postgres-xl: unable to redistribute a referenced table through newly added datanode

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, truncate, alter

I already have a functional postgres-xl. When I managed to add a new datanode to the cluster (which will be listed when I run `SELECT * FROM pgxc_node;`), no table automatically distribute on all nodes. So as ill documentation says I tried to redistribute with command `ALTER TABLE t1 ADD NODE (dn3);` (table t1 is referenced by table t2 with a foreign key on column col1. Both tables have been distributed by this column col1) I get this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "t2" references "t1".
HINT:  Truncate table "t2" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

I dont know how to follow the hint above!, Is there anything I'm missing? Honestly after making all severe changes to the database to get it work on postgres-xl I genuinely hoped that the one major benefit of that would be the ability to add datanode and direct newly added records evenly on all datanodes (or even redistribute existing ones on all nodes too) but getting this error is like a slap in the face.
Any help please?

Comment: As much as I've heard postgres-xl is all talk and no action so I recommend that you switch to some more reliable platform such as Citus